# How to retrieve end of day security price from bloomberg using Java on a Unix machine?

Tags: java, finance, bloomberg

I need to retrieve market close price of securities from bloomberg using Java on a Unix machine. How can I do that?

I browsed http://www.bloomberg.com/professional/software_support/ and have no idea which one should I use. If there's such java API, where could I access its Javadoc? Thank you!

Comment: I browsed through the link and I was not able to find any indication of Web services. If Bloomberg has a data retrieval Web service, you can use URL and URLConnection class to connect to it (depending upon their API, you have to make either REST or SOAP request), retrieve the data in either XML/JSON and parse it. For parsing JSON data, I'd recommend FlexJSON parser.

Comment: if there is no api or web-service available than i suppose you have to scrap the data from its website[web scraping]. For that i would recommend `htmlcleaner`.

Comment: @codeplay this access is against payment, you have been Bloomberg user before, because (as I know) you needed istaled Blooberg SW on local PC (server), true is that I never need to solve that this way because I'm BBE user, same for Reuters, and all Market Makers, Providers, Boerses ...,

Comment: Closing prices are delivered by default 1) own deals on BBE market, 2) closing prices from Boerses, 3) closing prices from Market makers, 4) indicates prices from issuer for private emision 5) another ZOO in some variations, most valuable are closing prices from local Boerses, because there are deals done, all another variations are Brookers, and Brooker sell/buy Securities on Local Boerse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options available:

1. You license the Bloomberg Server API - and then you are only able to distribute this data to Bloomberg anywhere users
2. You subscribe to Bloomberg's back office datalicense files for the products you are interested in, and download their nightly files

Your Bloomberg rep will be able to provide details for both options & appropriate documentation.  Type `BREP` to see contact details for your rep.

Answer (score 0):

Bloomberg has given API for Java, C, C++, C# and R. So you can use the api. The documentation is given in http://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

The above two options are correct however there is a third way:

> "Data License Per Security".

As the name suggests this follows a billing by usage model.
There are two ways of accessing it:

- SFTP back and forth of request and response files, users are authenticated by either user id / password / IP whitelist or ssl key exchange.
- Web Services. users are supplied with a ssl certificate for authentication purposes.